# Stringify macro with GNU gfortran

Tags: fortran, preprocessor, gfortran, stringify, stringification

How can I stringify a preprocessor macro with GNU gfortran? I would like to pass a macro definition to GNU gfortran which will then be used as a string in the code.

Effectively I would like to do this:

```
program test
implicit none
character (len=:), allocatable :: astring
astring = MYMACRO
write (*, *) astring
end program test
```

and then build with:

```
gfortran -DMYMACRO=hello test.F90
```

I tried creating various macro, for example:

```
#define STRINGIFY_(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY_(x)
...
astring = STRINGIFY(MYMACRO)
```

but this doesn't work with the gfortran preprocessor.

I also tried using a different style of macro:

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) "x"
...
astring = STRINGIFY(MYMACRO)
```

but this just creates a string containing the text 'MYMACRO'.

I then tried changing the macro definition to:

```
-DMYMACRO=\"hello\"
```

but this caused unrelated problem in the build process.

Thank you for your help

Comment: `-DMYMACRO=\"hello\"` is the right approach. Which problems did it cause?

Comment: @VladimirF Escaping the quotes works fine in my example code but in the actual project, some complexities of the build process causes it to fail. Changing the build procedure is not really an option, so I would like to find an alternative method if possible.

Comment: Could you be more specific as to why escaping the quotes does not work in the real project? It is hard to provide solutions with an unknown requirement.

Comment: @Ross Elsewhere in the build process, all the compiler flags are surrounded by quotes and included in a source file. Adding \" around the macro definition causes the compiler to fail.

Comment: @VladimirF I updated the question to include `#define STRINGIFY(x) "x"`. I found that it just created a string containing the text 'MYMACRO'.

Comment: OK, finally I get where is the difference from the question I linked before. Unfortunately, I don't know the solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your attempt to use the well-known stringification recipe of the C preprocessor,
viz:

```
#define STRINGIFY_(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY_(x)
```

fails for two reasons, each sufficient by itself.

First and simplest, the source file in which you attempt to employ it apparently 
has the extension `.f90`. What this extension signifies to `gfortran` (and to
the GCC compiler driver, by any other name) is: *Free form Fortran source code that should not be preprocessed.*
Similarly `.f95`, `.f03` and `.f08`. If you want `gfortran` to infer that a source
file contains free form Fortran code that *must* be preprocessed, give it one of
the extensions `.F90`, `.F95`, `.F03` or `.F08`. See [the GCC documentation of
these points](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options)

Even if you do that simple thing, however, the second reason bites.

The use of the C preprocessor to preprocess Fortran source is as old as C
(which though old, is much younger than Fortran). `gfortran` is obliged not
to break ancient working code; so, when it invokes the C preprocessor,
it invokes it in *traditional mode*. The *traditional mode* of the C preprocessor
is the way in which the preprocessor behaved prior to the first standardization
of the C language (1989), insofar as that unstandardized behaviour can be pinned down. In traditional
mode, the preprocessor does not recognize the stringizing operator '#', which was
introduced by the first C Standard. You can verify this by invoking the preprocessor
directly like:

```
cpp -traditional test.c
```

where `test.c` contains some attempt to employ the stringification recipe. The
attempt fails.

You cannot coax `gfortran` on its own to work the the stringification recipe.

But there is a workaround. You can invoke `cpp` directly, unencumbered by traditional mode,
to preprocess the Fortran source in which you want the stringification done and relay its
output to `gfortran`. If you already know this and were looking for a `gfortran`-alone
solution you need read no further.

Doing the stringification in your test source this way would look like:

```
cpp -std=c89 '-DSTRINGIFY_(x)=#x' '-DSTRINGIFY(x)=STRINGIFY_(x)' '-DMYMACRO=STRINGIFY(hello)' test.f90
```

The output of that is:

```
# 1 "test.f90"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "test.f90"
program test
implicit none
character (len=:), allocatable :: astring
astring = "hello"
write (*, *) astring
end program test
```

And that output is what you want to to compile. You could accomplish that as well by:

```
cpp -std=c89 '-DSTRINGIFY_(x)=#x' '-DSTRINGIFY(x)=STRINGIFY_(x)' \
'-DMYMACRO=STRINGIFY(hello)' test.f90 > /tmp/test.f90 \
&& gfortran -o test /tmp/test.f90
```

Then you will find that `./test` exists and that executing it outputs `hello`.

You can eliminate the intermediate temporary file with further refinement. Your F90 source
code will compile as F95, as the latter is conservative of the former. So you can take
advantage of the fact that GCC will compile source piped to its standard input if
you tell it what language you are piping, using its `-x` *language* option. The
Fortran dialects that you may specify in this way are `f77`, `f77-cpp-input`, `f95`
and `f95-cpp-input`, where the `-cpp-input` prefix denotes that
the source is to be preprocessed and its absence denotes that it is not. Thus

```
cpp -std=c89 '-DSTRINGIFY_(x)=#x' '-DSTRINGIFY(x)=STRINGIFY_(x)' \
'-DMYMACRO=STRINGIFY(hello)' test.f90 |  gfortran -x f95 -o test -
```

works as well as the previous solution, minus the temporary file, and emits
the innocuous warning:

```
Warning: Reading file '<stdin>' as free form
```

(*Note and retain the final* `-` *on the commandline. That is what tells `gfortran` to
compile the standard input.*). The meaning of `-x f95` brings the additional
economy that the source, which is preprocessed by `cpp`, is not preprocessed
again by the compiler.

The use of the option `-std=c89` when invoking `cpp` calls for a cautionary
explanation. It has the effect of making `cpp` conform to the earliest C Standard.
That is as close to `-traditional` as we can get while still availing of the
`#`-operator, on which the stringification recipe depends, But with it you embrace
the possibility of breaking *some* Fortran code if you preprocess it this way;
otherwise `gfortran` itself would not enforce `-traditional`. In the case of
your test program, you could safely omit `-std=c89`, allowing `cpp` to conform
to the default C standard when it was built. But if you permit it or direct it
to conform to `-std=c99` or later, then the standard will mandate recognition
of `//` as the beginning of a one-line comment (as per C++), by which any line
of Fortran that contains the concatenation operator will be truncated at the
first occurrence.

Naturally, if you use are using `make` or another build system to build the
code in which you want the stringified macros, you will have a way of telling
the build system what actions constitute *compiling* a given class of compilable
files. For any Fortran source file `fsrc` you wanted to compile with
a stringification preamble, the actions to specify would be in the vein:

```
cpp -std=c89 '-DSTRINGIFY_(x)=#x' '-DSTRINGIFY(x)=STRINGIFY_(x)' \
'-DMYMACRO=STRINGIFY(hello)' fsrc.f90 | gfortran -x f95 -c -o fsrc.o -
```

Comment: Thank you for writing such a comprehensive answer.

In response to your first point, that was just a typo on my part -- I was using the .F90 suffix rather than .f90. I have edited the question to reflect this.

On the second point, you have answered my question with "You cannot coax gfortran on its own to work the the stringification recipe". It looks like I am either going to have to find a different way to do what I want, or convince the project owner to modify their build procedure. The remainder of your second answer gives me a solution to offer.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is an old and answered question, I wanted to achieve macro stringification in gfortran without changing the default preprocessor or build process. I found that the preprocessor would do what I want, as long as there was no initial quotation mark on the line, therefore the desired stringification can be achieved by breaking lines with ampersands:

```
astring = "&
&MYMACRO"
```

A caveat is that this really only works with the traditional preprocessor, and for examples breaks with intel ifort compiler, which is too smart to fall for this trick. My current solution is to define separate stringification macros for gfortran as:

```
#ifdef __GFORTRAN__
# define STRINGIFY_START(X) "&
# define STRINGIFY_END(X) &X"
#else /* default stringification */
# define STRINGIFY_(X) #X
# define STRINGIFY_START(X) &
# define STRINGIFY_END(X) STRINGIFY_(X)
#endif

program test
implicit none
character (len=:), allocatable :: astring
astring = STRINGIFY_START(MYMACRO)
STRINGIFY_END(MYMACRO)
write (*, *) astring
end program test
```

It looks really ugly, but it does get the job done.

Comment: Great trick! Although it's a little cumbersome to use, it's the only real solution for big projects where changing the build process is out of the question.

Answer (score -2):

Removing the quotes around `x` in `STRINGIFY` solved the problem for me:

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) x   ! No quotes here
program test
    implicit none
    character (len=:), allocatable :: astring
    astring = STRINGIFY(MYMACRO)
    write(*,*), astring
end program test
```

Compiled with

```
gfortran -cpp -DMYMACRO=\"hello\" test.f90
```

The `-cpp` option enables the preprocessor for all extensions.

Comment: Well yes, but the point is in the `#` operator to concatenate two strings. The macro you show does literally nothing.