# Concatenating an expanded macro and a word using the Fortran preprocessor

Tags: macros, fortran, c-preprocessor, gfortran, intel-fortran

I'm trying to concatenate a word in the source code with the expansion of a preprocessor macro. Basically I have `foo` somewhere in the code, and with a `#define EXPANSION bar` I want to obtain `foobar`. However, I'm struggling to find a way to do this, which works with all compilers. For the moment I would be happy if it works with gfortran and ifort.

According to its [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Traditional-macros.html#Traditional-macros), the gfortran preprocessor is a C preprocessor running in "traditional mode", which does not have the `##` token paste operator. However, the same effect can be obtained with an empty C-style `/**/` comment. The ifort preprocessor seems to behave more like the normal C preprocessor, so normal token pasting does the trick in ifort. Unfortunately the empty `/**/` comment does not work in ifort, as the comment is replaced by a single space instead.

Here is a little example:

```
#define EXPANSION bar
#define CAT(x,y) PASTE(x,y)
#define PASTE(x,y) x ## y

foo/**/EXPANSION   
CAT(foo,EXPANSION)
```

For which gfortran produces:

```
foobar
foo ## bar
```

While ifort gives me:

```
foo bar
foobar
```

Of course I could choose the right way by checking the predefined macros for both compilers:

```
#ifdef __GFORTRAN__
foo/**/EXPANSION
#else
CAT(foo,EXPANSION)
#endif
```

This works for both of them, but it's rather ugly to have the preprocessor conditional for every expansion. I would much rather avoid this and have some macro magic only once in the beginning.

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31753386/1746785) to another question, which would probably allow me to work around this issue, but I would rather find a solution that does not invoke the preprocessor separately.

I'm not too familiar with the C preprocessor. Maybe there is a simple way to do what I want. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I've already tried something like this:

```
#define EXPANSION bar
#define CAT(x,y) PASTE(x,y)
#ifdef __GFORTRAN__
#define PASTE(x,y) x/**/y
#else
#define PASTE(x,y) x ## y
#endif

CAT(foo,EXPANSION)
```

Unfortunately this does not work in gfortran where it produces `fooEXPANSION`. I'm not entirely sure how this works, but apparently the expansion of the `CAT` macro prevents the expansion of `EXPANSION` in the same line. I suspect that this is a feature of the "traditional" C preprocessor ...

Comment: I think the answer is to define a `CONCAT` function which depends on the compiler. This can be used for all expansions. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39692172/6382074) for details

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've already tried something like this (see EDIT of the question). Couldn't make it work, unfortunately ...

Comment: Strange,  `x/**/y` produces `fooEXPANSION`, but ` x/**/ y`  produces `foo bar`. I recommend to formulate the question so that it attracts C preprocessor experts and they don't skip it because they would think it is Fortran specific (which it is not).

Comment: I think I understand this. The expansion of `CAT` happens first, producing `fooEXPANSION`. The word `EXPANSION` will then not be further expanded because it is not separated by a whitespace. If you put an additional whitespace before `y`, the expansion of `CAT` will produce `foo EXPANSION` which will be further expanded to `foo bar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done some research and it seems that basically most Fortran compilers (i.e. Intel and PGI) use a relatively normal C-preprocessor with a token pasting operator. We only need a special treatment for gfortran, which uses a C preprocessor in traditional mode without a token pasting operator.

Thanks to an [entry on c-faq.com](http://c-faq.com/cpp/oldpaste.html) I found this definition of a `CAT` macro that works with all compilers I tested so far:

```
#ifdef __GFORTRAN__
#define PASTE(a) a
#define CAT(a,b) PASTE(a)b
#else
#define PASTE(a) a ## b
#define CAT(a,b) PASTE(a,b)
#endif
```

Another solution (that still uses the `/**/` trick) was posted by [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1489985/1746785) to a related question.

Comment: So it is similar to the stringification trick I originally suggested...